# Cannot allocate available memory (even half!) on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, memory

I have two slightly different AWS EC2 instances of the same type with a huge amount of memory (`c4.8xlarge` with 60GB of RAM). One of those instances is just a copy which has been launched from a backup image (AMI) and the issue cannot be reproduced on it.

I stopped all of the services except system ones so most of the memory is free:

```
> free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          60382         201       59545           9         635       59695
Swap:             0           0           0
```

I cannot allocate **even half** of the available memory using `stress` utility:

```
> sudo stress --vm 1 --vm-keep --vm-bytes 30G
stress: info: [40005] dispatching hogs: 0 cpu, 0 io, 1 vm, 0 hdd
stress: FAIL: [40006] (494) hogvm malloc failed: Cannot allocate memory
...
```

And here is an output of `memtester`:

```
> sudo memtester 60000
memtester version 4.3.0 (64-bit)
Copyright (C) 2001-2012 Charles Cazabon.
Licensed under the GNU General Public License version 2 (only).

pagesize is 4096
pagesizemask is 0xfffffffffffff000
want 60000MB (62914560000 bytes)
got  29811MB (31259688960 bytes), trying mlock ...locked.
Loop 1:
  Stuck Address       : ok
  ...
```

There are no any `ulimit` memory restrictions enabled. I have the same issue on the copies of that server. But everything is fine on the server restored from the older image:

```
> stress --vm 1 --vm-keep --vm-bytes 58G
stress: info: [14516] dispatching hogs: 0 cpu, 0 io, 1 vm, 0 hdd


> sudo memtester 59000
memtester version 4.3.0 (64-bit)
Copyright (C) 2001-2012 Charles Cazabon.
Licensed under the GNU General Public License version 2 (only).

pagesize is 4096
pagesizemask is 0xfffffffffffff000
want 59000MB (61865984000 bytes)
got  59000MB (61865984000 bytes), trying mlock ...locked.
...
```

---

What can I do to figure out the issue?

Comment: What's different about this image and the older image?

Comment: We just installed some software by apt-get like postgresql and tomcat8.

Comment: Could this be NUMA related? `numactl --show` and `numactl --hardware` and other options might be useful.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I see the same output for both commands on both servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like somebody set the `vm.overcommit_memory` value to 2 in the new image.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting:

```
2   -   Don't overcommit. The total address space commit
        for the system is not permitted to exceed swap + a
        configurable amount (default is 50%) of physical RAM.
        Depending on the amount you use, in most situations
        this means a process will not be killed while accessing
        pages but will receive errors on memory allocation as
        appropriate.
```

To fix the issue - enable vm.overcommit_memory (by setting it to 0), or adjust vm.overcommit_ratio, or make a 30Gb swap.

Don't really know how to figure out such wierd problems, but I'd probably do the following things:

- Read all kernel docs related to memory management.
- Compare the `vm.*` sysctl parameters on both servers.
- Inspect the dmesg messages for hardware/system errors.
- Build the kernel with a debug information, attach a debugger, setup a breakpoint somewhere near the mmap syscall and look what's going.

Comment: It is exactly what I have! I changed `vm.overcommit_memory = 2` as recommended in official PostgreSQL docs — https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT
And I forgot about its side effect (my swap size was only 16GB).
The issue has gone with increasing the swap size!

Comment: It is then strange to use so much memory on your instance, leaving the postgresql without page-cache on which it should rely. I can suggest to check your installation with https://github.com/jfcoz/postgresqltuner. Also, it is ok to keep vm.overcommit_memory=0, to trade a bullet-proof stability of postgresql server for larger amount of connections, which is not a good practice though, but could be useful in some cases. Think about it to understood probable caveats.

Comment: Also, please make sure you understand the difference between "out of memory" and "cannot allocate memory" (i.e. allocation != usage)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is the linux kernel value of `vm.max_map_count` is constraining your app. It sets a max on the number of mmaps a process can have, which can yield heap allocation errors for apps like:

```bash
fatal error: out of memory allocating heap arena metadata
```

Read the current value with:

```bash
sudo sysctl vm.max_map_count
```

Update the value with:

```bash
# Double the value
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=131072

# Apply now during runtime
sudo sysctl -p
```